# Check if an array includes an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

The JavaScript `includes` function tells you whether an element is present in an array. Take the following example:

```js
var arr = ['hello', 2, 4, [1, 2]];

console.log( arr.includes('hello') );
console.log( arr.includes(2) );

console.log( arr.includes(3) );

console.log( arr.includes([1, 2]) );
```

Passing `'hello'` or `2` to the function returns `true`, since each of these is present in the array `arr`.

Passing `3` to the function returns `false` because this is not present in the array.

However, why does `arr.includes([1, 2])` also return `false`, even though this is equal to the last element in the array? And if this method does not work, how else can I find whether my array includes the item `[1, 2]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find a specific array in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58206905/how-to-find-a-specific-array-in-an-array)

Comment: I agree that it's a dupe, but I think this is the better question and answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.includes()` method uses [sameValueZero equality](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-samevaluezero) algorithm to determine whether an element is present in an array or not.

When the two values being compared are not numbers, `sameValueZero` algorithm uses [SameValueNonNumber](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-samevaluenonnumber) algorithm. This algorithm consists of 8 steps and the last step is relevant to your code , i.e. when comparison is made between two objects. This step is:

> 8. Return true if x and y are the same Object value. Otherwise, return false.

So in case of objects, `SameValueZero` algorithm returns true only if the two objects are *same*.

In your code, since the array `[1, 2]` inside `arr` array is identically different to `[1, 2]` that you passed to `.includes()` method, `.includes()` method can't find the array inside `arr` and as a result returns `false`.

Answer (score 3):

The `Array#includes` checks by shallow comparison, so in your case the string and numbers are *primitives* there is only ever a single instance of them so you get `true` from `Array#includes`.

But when you check for array, you are passing a new array instance which is not the same instance in the array you are checking so shallow comparison fails.

To check for an array is included in another array first check if it is an array then do a deep comparison between the arrays.

- Note that below snippet only works for an ***array of primitives***:

```js
var arr = ['hello', 2, 4, [1, 2]];
const includesArray = (data, arr) => {
  return data.some(e => Array.isArray(e) && e.every((o, i) => Object.is(arr[i], o)));
}

console.log(includesArray(arr, [1, 2]));
```

But if you keep the reference to the array `[1, 2]` and search with the reference the `Array#includes` works as in this case the shallow comparison works perfectly (obeying [same value zero algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)):

```js
const child =  [1, 2];
const arr = ['hello', 2, 4, child];

console.log(arr.includes(child));
```

Comment: Just found a bug in the `includesArray` algorithm e.g. `console.log(includesArray(arr, [1, 2, 3]));` returns `true` instead of `false`. The array `[1, 2, 3]` is NOT present in `arr`, yet is found.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using [lodash](https://lodash.com/), this algorithm is accurate.

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

export const includesArray = (haystack, needle) => {
    for (let arr of haystack)
        if (_.isEqual(arr, needle)) {
            return true
    }
    return false
}
```